# How do I scale JXMonthView?

Tags: java, swing, datepicker, swingx

Hi everyone reading this.
I am currently developing a program, that should run well displayed in different resolutions and thus has a scaling factor.

There is ne component, that I cannot find a solution for scaling for: 
The JXDatePicker and its JXMonthView.
What I tried:

```
final JXDatePicker datePicker = new JXDatePicker(new Date());
final JXMonthView monthView = datePicker.getMonthView();
monthView.setBounds(hauptFrame.getSize().width / 2 - (100*ViewerDefaults.SZ_INCR), (165*ViewerDefaults.SZ_INCR), (200*ViewerDefaults.SZ_INCR), (200*ViewerDefaults.SZ_INCR));
monthView.setSize(monthView.getWidth() * ViewerDefaults.SZ_INCR, monthView.getHeight() * ViewerDefaults.SZ_INCR);
monthView.setPreferredColumnCount(1);
monthView.setPreferredRowCount(1);
monthView.setTraversable(true);
monthView.setZoomable(true);
datePicker.setSize(datePicker.getWidth() * 2, datePicker.getHeight() * 2);
```

ViewerDefaults.SZ_INCR is the scaling factor and would replace the 2 in the last line, if working.

I added the setPreferredColumnCount(1) and setPreferredRowCount(1) as I tried setting the size of the JXMonthview before, but I ended up having 4 months displayed next to each other, whereas I just wanted a single, larger displayed month.

Can you help and show me a way to enlarge the display of only on month?

EDIT:
I translated everything into using Layout Managers. The problematic behaviour remains: The month displayed is not scaled up, but simply displayed in the center. To give some more insight to the code I put the whole method here as follows(size is set earlier by Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();):

```
private static JPanel licBorrowPanel = null;
licBorrowPanel = new JPanel();
licBorrowPanel.setBounds(0, 20, size.width, size.height-20); 
licBorrowPanel.setVisible(false);
licBorrowPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

public static void licenceBorrowDialog() {

licBorrowPanel.setSize(new Dimension(hauptFrame.getSize().width, hauptFrame.getSize().height));
licBorrowPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
licBorrowPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
licBorrowPanel.setVisible(true);

//Create upper part of licBorrowPanel
JPanel licBorrowTop = new JPanel();
licBorrowTop.setLayout(new BoxLayout(licBorrowTop, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));  

// Label Titel
JLabel labelTitel = new JLabel("License borrwing");
labelTitel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
labelTitel.setFont(ViewerDefaults.DEF_LABEL_FONT);
licBorrowTop.add(labelTitel);

// Header Calendar
JLabel calendarTitle = new JLabel("Please select a date", SwingConstants.LEFT);
calendarTitle.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
calendarTitle.setFont(ViewerDefaults.DEF_ROW_FONT);
licBorrowTop.add(calendarTitle);

licBorrowPanel.add(licBorrowTop, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);


//Create central part of licBorrowPanel
JPanel licBorrowCenter = new JPanel();
licBorrowCenter.setLayout(new BoxLayout(licBorrowCenter, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

// Label selectedDate
final JLabel labelSelectedDate = new JLabel("<HTML><BODY> </HTML></BODY>");
labelSelectedDate.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
labelSelectedDate.setFont(ViewerDefaults.DEF_LIC_FONT);
labelSelectedDate.setText("<HTML><BODY><b>Some Text</HTML></BODY>");

// Calendar
final JXDatePicker datePicker = new JXDatePicker(new Date());
final JXMonthView monthView = datePicker.getMonthView();
monthView.setPreferredColumnCount(1);
monthView.setPreferredRowCount(1);
monthView.setZoomable(true); //Removing this results in several Columns and Rows being displayed.

// Set selection to "in two days" as default
Date newDate = monthView.getSelectionDate();
newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate()+2);

datePicker.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    //...
});
licBorrowCenter.add(monthView, BorderLayout.CENTER);
licBorrowCenter.add(labelSelectedDate, BorderLayout.CENTER);

// Footer Calendar
JLabel calendarSubTitle = new JLabel("<HTML><BODY><CENTER>Some other Text.</CENTER></HTML></BODY>", SwingConstants.LEFT);
calendarSubTitle.setFont(ViewerDefaults.DEF_FONT);
calendarSubTitle.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
calendarSubTitle.setFont(ViewerDefaults.DEF_ROW_FONT);
calendarSubTitle.setForeground(Color.RED);
licBorrowCenter.add(calendarSubTitle, BorderLayout.CENTER);

licBorrowPanel.add(licBorrowCenter);


//Create lower part of licBorrowPanel
JPanel licBorrowBottom = new JPanel();
licBorrowBottom.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

// Button OK
JButton buttonLicBorrowOK = new JButton("OK");
buttonLicBorrowOK.setFont(ViewerDefaults.DEF_LIC_FONT);
licBorrowBottom.add(buttonLicBorrowOK, BorderLayout.LINE_START);

// Button Return
JButton buttonLicReturn = new JButton("Return");
buttonLicReturn.setFont(ViewerDefaults.DEF_LIC_FONT);
licBorrowBottom.add(buttonLicReturn, BorderLayout.CENTER);

// Button Cancel
JButton buttonLicBorrowCancel = new JButton("Cancel");
buttonLicBorrowCancel.setFont(ViewerDefaults.DEF_LIC_FONT);
licBorrowBottom.add(buttonLicBorrowCancel, BorderLayout.LINE_END);

licBorrowPanel.add(licBorrowBottom, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);


// Update licBorrowPanel
licBorrowPanel.update(licBorrowPanel.getGraphics());

// several action listeners for buttons eluded..
```

}

"hauptframe" is the parent JFrame.
An additional problem occurred, but I think this will be solved once the JXMonthView is displayed as wanted: The licBorrowBottom is not displayed.

I hope this clarifies the problem and helps helping :)

Comment: *that should run well displayed in different resolutions and thus has a scaling factor* Well it looks like a nice job for [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html) instead of manual scaling. IMHO this is a case of an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: It does get displayed. Only the monthview is very tiny on higher resolutions.

Comment: I am currently coding to get LayoutManagement working and will come back with my result.